# PHP SOAP : Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I have the following error:

> "PHP SOAP : Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] An
> Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"

I have tried to set up soap headers but it is not working:

```
$authvalues = array("username"=>"@@@@","password"=>"EEEEE");
$header =  new SoapHeader("SoapBaseNameSpace","ReqHeader", $authvalues, true);

$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting it in the options array?

```
$options = array(
  "login" => 'login',
  "password" => 'pass'
);

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
```